# Node JS server quit sending files all of a sudden

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

This was working exactly as it is 2 days ago, I come back to it today, and when I connect from anything other than localhost(including putting IP in address bar instead of the word "localhost", it's just a white page with no error. Here's the code, it's pretty short, so I don't really know where the issue is.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
    res.sendFile();
});

io.on('connection', function(socket)
{
    socket.on('shipID', function(data)
    {
        socket.broadcast.emit('shipID', data);
    });

    socket.on('requestID', function()
    {
        socket.broadcast.emit('requestID');
    });

    socket.on('move', function(data)
    {
        socket.broadcast.emit('move', data);
    });
});

http.listen(80, function()
{
    console.log('listening on localhost:80');
});
```

As a side note, making that block of code ^ in this text box was obnoxious, is there an easier way to do it other than pressing space 4x at the beginning of each line?

Comment: You can just paste the code, select it, and hit the Code button in your formatting palette (just one way of doing it)

Comment: I changed the last bit to:
   app.listen(80);
and it still works.  I also stuck a console.log inside of the app.get and it doesn't ever fire.  I don't get why this works on localhost but not others.  Is it just going to the actual files when I connect with localhost and not sending anything?  If it's sending nothing though, shouldn't I be getting a 403?

Comment: Does the `public` folder contain an `index.html`? Also note that [`res.sendFile()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) expects a `path` argument.

Comment: Apparently app.use overwrites the app.get anyway, so that's why that wasn't being hit.  and yes, public does contain an index.html file.

Comment: [Ctrl]+[K] indents a multi-line selection...

Comment: Having `app.get('/')` and a `public/index.html`, your application has defined the home page twice. But, the server can only reply with one of them and it will use the first of them, following the order in your code – `app.use(express.static())` before `app.get('/')`.

Comment: That's the weird thing, when I use localhost, I don't set any path at all. just "localhost" in the URL and it works just fine. 2 days ago it worked like that from all local connections as well. Now it doesn't.

Comment: @Zarthias It's possible your browser may be holding in cache a copy of the home page, displaying that again. And, the cache is built up for each hostname, regardless of whether they're the same server application. Check the Network in your browser's dev tools. In Chrome, at least, you'll see "(from cache)" in the "Size" column in that case.

Comment: It's 304s, but in "size" it doesn't say "from cashe"

Comment: Now that I think about it though, it can't be using cached version, because I can modify the index.html and the changes are reflected.

Comment: I finally found the problem.  Windows 10 decided port 80 isn't allowed for some reason. changed to 8080 and it works fine.  So i've been looking in the code all this time for no reason.  The problem is windows.

Comment: For some reason though, I can bind to 80 just fine.  The traffic just doesn't come through today.  I tried port forwarding in the router and I tried opening the port in the firewall.  Still won't work.